# IMPORTXML How to format imported text without line breaks?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using the IMPORTXML formula in a cell to import text.  The text on the web page doesn't have defined line breaks, nor does the source code, but the import I get does.  I need it to be one string, so I can format it correctly.

```
=importxml("https://elite.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL&ty=l&ta=0&p=m", "//td[@class='fullview-profile']")
```

[The text breaks that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC3Y0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.  Wrapping the formula in Clean()

```
=clean(importxml("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL&ty=l&ta=0&p=m", "//td[@class='fullview-profile']"))
```